# Why is only the first element appearing from html string through XMLHttp request?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to dynamically load mp3 files to a webpage via XMLHttp request. It is in a string, and there should be two divs with audio files appearing. However, only the first one is appearing. Could someone please help me determine why this is happening? I want to be able to load more files to the source page and have them appear dynamically on this webpage.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML lang="en-US">
<HEAD>
<TITLE>load files</TITLE>  

<Style>
   body{
       background-color: blue;
   }

   .container{
       border:5px solid white;
       margin:10%;
       width:600px;
       height:600px;

   }

   .floating {
     display: inline-block;
     width: 150px;
     height: 75px;
     margin: 10px;
     border: 3px solid #73AD21;  
  }

</Style>
<SCRIPT>
  function get_list_of_files_from_html( html_string ){
    var el = document.createElement( 'html' );
    el.innerHTML = html_string;

    var list_of_files = el.getElementsByTagName( 'a' ); 

    var return_string = '<div class="floating">';

    for(var i=5; i < list_of_files.length ; i++){
      var current_string = list_of_files[i];
      var new_string  = current_string.toString()
        .replace('http://www.website.com/~user/final/','');
      return_string += 
        '<audio controls><source src ="' + new_string + 
        '" type=audio/mpeg></audio>';
      return_string += '</div>';

      return return_string;
    }
  }

  function loadDoc(){
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("container").innerHTML =
        get_list_of_files_from_html( this.responseText);
      }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", 
      "http://www.website.com/~user/final/audiofiles/", true);
      xhttp.send();
  }

</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
  <body onload="loadDoc()">
  <div id="container"  class="container"></div>
</body>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: okay thanks that made it work without the quotations, i was trying to figure out what the problem was there. by the way, do you know what type of syntax I would use  within this code to hide the audio files and have the music play/pause on the respective divs? I only know how to do it in the body with onclick function(). There arent any answers about it on here, or I just don't know what to look for.

Comment: To hide the audio controls, just don't include the `controls` attribute in the tag. To add your own play/pause and volume controls, you'll need to include HTML elements for users to click on and then set the click events of those elements up to callback functions that use the **[Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API)**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: You've indicated that you needed to do a global replace on your strings. For that, you'll need to use a regular expression of:

```
/http:\/\/www.website.com\/~user\/final\//gi
```

The forward slashes in the string need to be escaped. You probably also want `gi` for global and case insensitive.

In any event, your code should be reorganized to follow modern standards. While HTML is not case-sensitive, it is generally written in all lower case (`<style>`, not `<Style>`, etc.) and JavaScript identifiers should be in `camelCase`, not underscored between every word `with_long_names_for_stuff`. You also have several unnecessary bits of code. See the comments inline below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
  <title>load files</title>  
  <style>
    body { background-color: blue; }

    .container {
      border:5px solid white;
      margin:10%;
      width:600px;
      height:600px;
    }

    .floating {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 150px;
      height: 75px;
      margin: 10px;
      border: 3px solid #73AD21;  
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container" class="container"></div>
  
  <!-- Place your scripts just before the close of the body tag and they will
       run as soon as the DOM is built, eliminating the need for: body.onload = ...-->
  <script>
    
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = getFileList(this.responseText);
      }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "http://www.website.com/~user/final/audiofiles/", true);
    xhttp.send();
   
    // Follow standard naming conventions. Don't make crazy long function or variable names
    function getFileList(html){
    
      // Don't create a new HTML element to hold the passed string.
      // Use something that body content normally would go in:
      var el = document.createElement(div');
      el.innerHTML = html;

      // Don't use .getElementsByTagName() as this returns a "live" node list.
      // Instead, use the more efficient, modern approach and place the results
      // in a JavaScript array so that you can loop with .forEach() later:
      var fileList = Array.prototype.slice.call(el.querySelectorAll('a')); 

      var retVal = '<div class="floating">';
      
      // Loop through the array with Array.forEach() which is simpler than
      // setting up counters and managing them:
      fileList.forEach(function(file, idx){
        // Do you really want to ignore the first 6 items?
        if(idx >= 5){
          // No need to call .toString() on string data
          // Use a regular expression to do a global replace on the string
          retVal += '<audio controls><source src ="' +                                  
                    file.replace(/http:\/\/www.website.com\/~user\/final\//gi,'') + 
                    '" type=audio/mpeg></audio></div>';
        }
      });
      
      return retVal;
    } 
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Scott, for some reason I was taught to do it with underscores! I figured it out though..I need to use a global replace.

Comment: @plutoneedshelp I'll update my answer to show the global replace. Glad you found it. Also, different languages use different standards, but JS doesn't follow the underscore convention.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to use a global variable, so `/http://www.website.com/~user/final//g` instead of `http://www.website.com/~user/final/`

Comment: Actually it's `/http:\/\/www.website.com\/~user\/final\//gi`. The forward slashes in the string need to be escaped. You probably also want `gi` for global and case insensitive.